# Generic Task method for EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to create a generic method that starts a new task > creates a unique instance of my db context (since EF dbcontext isn't thread safe and I want to execute many taks in parallel) > enumerate the result by `ToList()`:ing it.

Here is my psuedo-code that obviusly won't compile. I need your help refining it to the correct syntax:

```
private Task<T> DoGenericStuff<T>(T dbContext, Func<T, bool> func)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var context = Activator.CreateInstance(dbContext.GetType()))
        {
            return context.func.ToList();
        }
    });
}
```

-

```
Func<SYSTEM, bool> func = x => x.SYSTEM_KEY == 123;
var task = DoGenericStuff(DbContext, func);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private Task<TResult> DoGenericStuff<TDbContext, TResult>(Func<TDbContext, TResult> func) where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var context = new TDbContext())
        {
            return func(context);
        }
    });
}
```

Execute using:

```cs
var task = DoGenericStuff<MyDbContext, bool>(context => context.Set<MyEntity>().Any());
```

The function takes a delegate with a single argument of a `DbContext` and can return arbitrary values. The type of `DbContext` is specified in the generic arguments to the function call. If you want to `.ToList()` the results, then do that in the lambda. The code (as per your pseudo code) requires that the `DbContext` has a parameterless constructor.